# filtrar fecha y hora cada 30 minutos

Tags: excel

Estimados tengo una tabla con varios datos en la cual necesito solo filtrar los datos cada 30 minutos como puedo realizar esta operacion?

```
Ejemplo
```

datos sin filtrar

```
03-01-2018 13:08
03-01-2018 13:13
03-01-2018 13:19
03-01-2018 13:24
03-01-2018 13:29
03-01-2018 13:34
03-01-2018 13:39
03-01-2018 13:44
03-01-2018 13:49
03-01-2018 13:54
03-01-2018 13:59
03-01-2018 14:04
03-01-2018 14:09
```

Datos filtrados

```
03-01-2018 13:08
03-01-2018 13:34
03-01-2018 14:04
```

Comment: Falta información, has probado algo? solo es posible utilizar Excel? es posible acudir a VBA? Por otra parte, deben ser registros únicos? (p.e. 13:08 y 13:09) y si lo son con cual nos quedamos, con el primero? Deberías clarificar mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: los datos son tal cual los muestro cada 5 minutos aprox, si se puede acudir a VBA

Comment: Redondea las horas a formatos de media hora en media hora, y agrupa con una tabla dinámica

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la fecha la puedes extraer con

```
=TEXTO(A2;"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

y luego nada más filtras por fecha y hora

Con esto ya encaminarse a lo que ud quiere